# How to reduce index scan by avoid scaning null values

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, nullable, non-clustered-index

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to add a non-clustered index on a non-unique, nullable field. My index will also have one more column included in order to avoid accessing my clustered index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_My_Index 
ON MyTable (myBasicField) 
INCLUDE (myIncludedField);
```

In the actual data of `myBasicField` there will be a lot of `NULLs` and I was wondering if there is a way I can increase performance by not scanning these `NULLs`, or prevent `NULL` values to be stored on my index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like the filtered index answer.  This is just something else.  You could put that data in a separate table with a FK relationship and then you eliminate the null altogether (if it is null then no row in the FK table.).  A PK to FK join is pretty fast if both are clustered index.

Comment: I wanted to confirm that Sql Server does include NULLs in indexes (it does) - [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/cc280372(v=sql.100)#filtered-indexes-for-subsets-of-data) (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687291/4289902))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008 and newer, you could use a **filtered index**. See an [intro blog post here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/01/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-filtered-index-improve-performance-with-filtered-index/) - syntax would be:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_My_Index 
ON MyTable (myBasicField) 
INCLUDE (myIncludedField)
WHERE myBasicField IS NOT NULL;
```

Any query that contains the same `WHERE` clause can take advantage of this, and the index will be a lot smaller and thus perform better if you exclude NULL values like this.

Comment: +1   If the user query was where myBasicField IS NULL then you would get a full table scan?

Comment: @Blam: possibly - depends on what other criteria there might be in your query. If `myBasicField` is NULL, then **this** index will definitely not be used.

Comment: Thank you guys for your fast responses. That's what I needed

Comment: By the way, is there anything similar I can do in SQL Server 2005? We have few clients not upgraded yet, so I will need sth there too.

Comment: @zafeiris.m: no, unfortunately - this is a new feature in SQL Server **2008**

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a filtered index. See:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer [i have too few reputation to vote you up, sorry :)]. I'll check this and let you know