# SQL Server Update Queries Taking Too Long

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a SQL query that builds analysis tables using SELECT INTO statements from populated staging tables. This part goes pretty smooth, but when I try to append fields to the analysis tables, from each other or from the original staging tables, the UPDATE queries run for HOURS.

I feel this run time is unwarranted because the most records per table is 200K. I have a feeling that this is an issue with my log file management or the fact that I have no indexes on any of these tables. I have been reluctant to build indexes because I know if hastily done, they can actually cause more problems. There are no triggers on any of these tables.

I am trying to find an approach so that this query runs consistently. In the past, it has run under 1 hour (which is still probably too long) but today for instance it has taken 3+ hours.

I've already modified the log file to autogrow by 50% rather than 10%, to have an unlimited MAXSIZE, I've set the DB recovery mode to SIMPLE and I have shrunk the log file manually. None of this is helping.

I know that TABLE SCANS are a source of lag in large queries, **so is the solution here to create indexes for all of the fields I use in my LEFT JOINs depicted below?** These snippets are exact examples of where the query is lagging. I have transparency into this because I am following the execution of the script in the LIVE QUERY STATISTICS window.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[Account ID] = b.[Account ID]
FROM SFAX.dbo.Leads as a
left join SFAX.dbo.Accts as b on a.[Company   Account] = b.[Account Name]
WHERE a.[Account ID] IS NULL;

-- Link by website2
UPDATE a
SET a.[Account ID] = b.[Account ID]
FROM SFAX.dbo.Leads as a
left join SFAX.dbo.Accts as b on a.url2 = b.Website2
WHERE a.[Account ID] IS NULL;
--
UPDATE a
SET a.[SFDC Account Name] = b.[Account Name]
FROM SFAX.dbo.Leads as a
left join SFAX.dbo.Accts as b on
a.[Account ID] = b.[Account ID]
WHERE a.[Account ID] IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE a
SET a.ConvertedFlag = b.[Lead ID]
FROM SFAX.dbo.WhoAnalysis1 as a 
LEFT JOIN SFAX.dbo.Contacts as b ON a.WhoId = b.[Contact ID];
```

Comment: Please don't put spaces in column names

Comment: You should make indexes

Comment: You don't suppose that the `CREATE TABLE` statements might be of even the slightest interest?

Comment: I TRUNCATE existing tables and SELECT INTO to populate with new data. All of these queries run in seconds. Its the UPDATE queries that take hours

Comment: @Hogan is it really that simple? Just go through every field I am using for a JOIN and create an index?? The only reason I havent done this is because everything I've read says that indexes really only have an effect on SELECT statements not UPDATE

Comment: Everything you have read is wrong.

Comment: That was unclear, to be clear -- when you have a join in an update it is the same internally as a select AND an update.  The indexes will have a positive effect.

Comment: thank you for clarifying. just happy that you have helped. really appreciate it

Comment: Happy to help -- let us know how it goes

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** In the comments above you express doubt. This is easy to test -- break your script in half prior to updates -- run part one -- then run one update and time it. Then make indexes for that one update. Run it again. How many orders of magnitude faster is it?

Don't be scared of indexes if you work with SQL -- love your indexes. Create indexes for

```
SFAX.dbo.Leads.[Company   Account], [Account ID] 
SFAX.dbo.Accts.[Account Name]

SFAX.dbo.Leads.url2, [Account ID]
SFAX.dbo.Accts.Website2

SFAX.dbo.Leads.[Account ID]
SFAX.dbo.Accts.[Account ID]

SFAX.dbo.WhoAnalysis1.WhoID
SFAX.dbo.Contacts.[Contact ID]
```

But remember -- if you are changing a lot of records in your database this could be constrained by the speed of your I/O

Comment: Would there be anything standing out in the execution plan to serve as evidence these indexes are indeed needed? Wouldn't the null values in the index for [Account ID] require extra attention, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20687291/578411)?

Comment: I don't think I've ever see Aaron Bertrand be wrong but that seems to be in the realm of optimization to me.  We have a query that takes hours and should take seconds -- to the easy first and then optimize if needed.  The fact the execution plan has scans shows indexes would help.

Comment: @Hogan  trying to scale your suggestion to my entire script and I just want to be clear on something ... when I create the indexes, are you suggesting that I create it on only the fields being used in the JOINs? Or should I create an index on the field being used in the JOINs AND the field being SET by the UPDATE statement?

Comment: @hansolo -  The fields being used by the joins -- for both tables.  You are updating that field not reading it or searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

Below has a lot of nonsense work to do - so don't do it.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[Account ID] = b.[Account ID]
FROM SFAX.dbo.Leads as a
left join SFAX.dbo.Accts as b on a.[Company   Account] = b.[Account Name]
WHERE a.[Account ID] IS NULL;
```

If there is no match in b, you will set [a.Account ID] to null. But you are only selecting those rows in a where the column is NULL. **SO DON'T DO THAT** - your left join is pointless extra work. Change it to an inner join. Will that help significantly? Can't tell without knowing the characteristics of your data.

Comment: wow... that that is subtle -- it won't change the speed of the query unless there is an index, but good point.

Comment: that's a great suggestion that I never thought of. the inner join would help eliminate redundant statements.