# Filtr data by null or not null - is the index required?

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have table with many rows and nullable datetime column. I will only filter data on this table by checking if this column is null or not null. This is kind of auditing data and the value is changing only from null to some date.

Is the index non clustered index required for such case?
Sql server 2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does SQL Server Index Null Values in a Non-Clustered Non-Unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687213/does-sql-server-index-null-values-in-a-non-clustered-non-unique-index)

Comment: Check out Aaron Bertrand's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687213/does-sql-server-index-null-values-in-a-non-clustered-non-unique-index

Comment: Hmm thanx but I am still not sure. I don't plan to order or filter by date ranges etc. My primaru goal is find records with null value in this column

Answer (score 1):

You could create a filtered index on the column, but the only way to know if it helps your query is to perform good old fashioned query tuning.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FINullDateCol  
    ON <myTable> (DateCol)  
    WHERE DateCol IS NULL ;  
GO
```

Comment: In most cases I will query "select top X * from MyTable where MyColumn is null". Do I get any performance improvement when using filtered index? Ok I need to prepare some test data and check this.